# Multiplying a force vector by rotated unit vector produces strange results

Tags: rotational-dynamics, vectors, linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I'm by no means an expert in math, what I'm trying to do is to Isolate a force aligned with a vehicle in a game (specifically to do a directional friction).

the equation is simple I take a vector $v_1$ (1,0,0) rotate it by a quaternion rotation (this part works well I get a vector of length 1 that is rotated in space), and then I multiply another vector (force) by the rotated vector.

$v_2 = q * v_1 * q^{-1}$ (idk how to draw line above characters in mathjax, let's pretend this is a inverse quaternion)

$v_3 = F * v_1$

The thing is $v_3$ is all of a sudden not aligned with $v_1$ which makes absolutely no sense to me, As I imagine it, $v_3$ should point in the direction of $v_1$.

Am I missing something here? or does this look like a bug?

This is how it looks like in game:
The blue line is $v_1$ and the red line is $v_3$, as you can see $v_3$ isn't aligned properly (and it's shape wildly changes during runtime).

[image: image of two vectors above the car]

Comment: This may help - [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/294354). In particular, see item 13, \overline

Comment: Multiplying a Vector by a scalar does not change its direction, so this sounds like a bug rather than a physics problem.  I'd first check the type of F to make sure it's a scalar.  If it's a vector, then you're doing some vector-vector multiplication... exactly what that means will be specific to your library.

Comment: Are you plotting v1 and v3, or v2 and v3?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent oh you're right blue is v2 not v1, bc it's rotated

Comment: I am trying to get you to check if you are even comparing the correct things. Because if you did everything correctly, you should be obtaining the parallel-ness.

Comment: Related : **(1)** [Rotation of a vector](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252942/rotation-of-a-vector).. **(2)** [Why is there this relationship between quaternions and Pauli matrices?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/271419/why-is-there-this-relationship-between-quaternions-and-pauli-matrices/272563#272563).

Answer (score 1):

Please define what $*$ is in $v_3 = F * v_1$

You need to take the [dot product](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors-dot-product.html), and not any quaternion product or other product.

The reason I suspect you did not, is because the result isn't along the unit vector. If you use the dot product, then the result is the *magnitude* of the force vector along the direction.

To make it into a vector quantity multiply scale the unit vector $\hat{v}$ with the dot product value.

$$ \vec{F}_{\parallel} = ( \hat{v} \cdot \vec{F}) \hat{v}$$